# Model theoretic connected components. Reference request

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

I was wondering if there are any references about well known examples of connected components of type-definable groups (preferably in NIP theories). It would be great if there are also some hints on how they are computed.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.0137.pdf, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870812002095, and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007215000378

Comment: Thank you very much